# How cluster server works?

Tags: cluster

Now, I have a server running php + Mysql, but my server loading is very high, I want to start up one more server to reduce the workload, what should I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You will probably need to do a lot of reading.  Topics of particular interest include:

- MySQL replication
- Server load balancing
- High availability (HA)

Google search for all for all of these (throw in "apache" or "mysql") will probably yield useful results.  You will need to replicate your database data, and you will probably also want to replicate your static content between the two servers.  You may also need to arrange for ip load balancing, either via something like round-robin DNS + high availability software (heartbeat/pacemaker/etc) or through the use of yet another system as a load balancer.

This google search yielded a variety of interesting documents:

- http://goo.gl/eko2z

Answer (score 2):

Buy [MySQL Cluster](http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to be offtopic but...
More horsepower to that pc?

Adding ram is easy and cheap and can do the trick...